# How to use results from Swift completion handler?

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, completionhandler

I'm new to Swift and SwiftUI.

In my macOS SwiftUI project, I'm trying to verify that a URL is reachable so I can present one of two views conditionally.  One view which loads the image URL, another one which displays an error image if the URL is not reachable.

Here's my URL extension with completion:

```swift
import Foundation

extension URL {
    func isReachable(completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
        var request = URLRequest(url: self)
        request.httpMethod = "HEAD"
        request.timeoutInterval = 1.0
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            if error != nil {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completion(false)
                }
                return
            }
            if let httpResp: HTTPURLResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completion(httpResp.statusCode == 200)
                }
                return
            } else {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completion(false)
                }
                return
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

Elsewhere, I'm trying to use that in a model-view:

```swift
var imageURL: URL? {
    if let url = self.book.image_url {
        return URL(string: url)
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}

var imageURLIsReachable: Bool {
    if let url = self.imageURL {
        url.isReachable { result in
            return result  // Error: Cannot convert value of type 'Bool' to closure result type 'Void'
        }
    } else {
        return false
    }
}
```

Though Xcode is showing this error:

`Cannot convert value of type 'Bool' to closure result type 'Void'`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can't return a value *synchronously* via a computed property that is obtained *asynchronously*. In your completion handler you can assign the result to a property, and use another mechanism (`didSet` or via `@Published`) to act on the change.

Comment: http://www.programmingios.net/returning-a-value-from-asynchronous-code/ - You cannot return a Bool that depends on `url.isReachable` for the same reason that `url.isReachable` uses a completion handler: it is _asynchronous_. That means it happens in the future. People always say "I am new to Swift" etc. but surely one is not new to the idea that you cannot do _now_ something that depends on what _will_ happen in the future.

Comment: Not related to your question but 1 second timeout is too short to define is a remote URL is reachable or not. The default value for a URLRequest time out is 1 minute

Comment: @LeoDabus I'm only doing a `HEAD` request.  Do you think I need more than 1 second? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/HEAD

Comment: I don't know but not everybody has a good connection. Better to be safe than sorry. Btw the timeout has nothing to do with the time needed to complete the download

Comment: You can simplify your code `extension URL {`
`func isReachable(_ completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {` `var request = URLRequest(url: self)` `request.httpMethod = "HEAD"`
`URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { _, response, _ in` `guard let statusCode = (response as? HTTPURLResponse)?.statusCode, statusCode == 200 else {` `completion(false)` `return` `}` `completion(true)` `}.resume()` `}` `}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this to work after reading some of the comments here and doing more research/experimentation. Here's what I changed:

In the URL extension, I left it pretty much the same as I find it more readable this way.  I did push the `timeoutInterval` to a parameter:

```swift
// Extensions/URL.swift


import Foundation

extension URL {
    func isReachable(timeoutInterval: Double, completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
        var request = URLRequest(url: self)
        request.httpMethod = "HEAD"
        request.timeoutInterval = timeoutInterval
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            if error != nil {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completion(false)
                }
                return
            }
            if let httpResp: HTTPURLResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completion(httpResp.statusCode == 200)
                }
                return
            } else {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completion(false)
                }
                return
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

I modified my `BookViewModel` to make two of the properties to `@Published` and used the URL extension there:

```swift
// View Models/BookViewModel.swift

import Foundation

class BookViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var book: Book
    @Published var imageURLIsReachable: Bool
    @Published var imageURL: URL?
    
    init(book: Book) {
        self.book = book
        self.imageURL = nil
        self.imageURLIsReachable = false
        if let url = book.image_url {
            self.imageURL = URL(string: url)
            self.imageURL!.isReachable(timeoutInterval: 1.0) { result in
                self.imageURLIsReachable = result
            }
        }
    }
    
    // Rest of properties...
}
```

Now my `BookThumbnailView` can properly display the conditional views:

```swift
// Views/BookThumbnailView.swift

import SwiftUI
import Foundation
import KingfisherSwiftUI

struct BookThumbnailView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: BookViewModel
        
    private var book: Book {
        viewModel.book
    }
    
    @ViewBuilder
    var body: some View {
        if let imageURL = self.viewModel.imageURL {
            if self.viewModel.imageURLIsReachable {
                KFImage(imageURL)
                        .resizable()
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                        .frame(maxWidth: 70)
                        .cornerRadius(8)
            } else {
                ErrorBookThumbnailView()
            }
        } else {
            DefaultBookThumbnailView()
        }
    }
}
```

Whew, that was quite the learning experience. Thanks to everyone who commented with suggestions and provided hints on where to look!

Answer (score 0):

The problem literally laid in the line `return result`, as Xcode tells you. When you create your function `func isReachable(completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void)`, you are telling Xcode that you are going to input something in the type of `(Bool) -> Void`, which should be something like `func someFunction(input: Bool) -> Void`.

But when you use a closure to input the completion handler, you're inputting a function in type `Bool -> Bool`. Remove the line `return result`, or change the type of the completion in your `func isReachable(completion:)`.

**Edit:**

And indeed I don't recommend returning a async result in a computed property, that would cause some other problem.

I would change it to something like:

```
func isReachable(completion: @esacping (Bool) -> Void) {
    ...
}

func showResultView() {
    guard let url = imageURL else { 
        // handling if the imageURL is nil
        return
    }
    url.isReachable { result in
        // do something with the result
        if result {
            // show viewController A
        } else {
            // show viewController B
        }
    }
}

// call showResultView anywhere you want, lets say you want to show it whenever the viewController appear
override func viewDidAppear() {
    ...
    showResultView()
}
```

Comment: I've tried using that code in the View body, but that doesn't seem to be allowed. Where would you put that code?  Also, so far I don't have any ViewControllers; I'm mostly using MVVM. But I'm open to solutions to get this to work.  Thanks

Comment: Sorry I didn't make that clear enough, the code is not called directly in the View body. Please see my edited answer.

Comment: In my understand, MVVM focus on separate the View (the UI) and the Model (the data), it's not a must to not having any ViewController, so I am a bit confused of "I don't have any ViewControllers; I'm mostly using MVVM.", indeed in my project using MVVM do have viewController, viewModel, Model, and some View for reuse. But anyway, call it in the lifecycle of your View, or whenever you need it, but not directly paste that on the View's class body. Hope that make thing clear a little bit.

Comment: I read somewhere "SwiftUI kind of blends UIView and UIViewController into a single View protocol, which makes our code much simpler.".  So, I'll try adding that code to my related view.  Thanks again!